# Add additional targets to Prometheus inside Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, argocd

I am setting up Prometheus with Kubernetes and ArgoCD.
I am using this helm chart for Prometheus [kube-prometheus-stack](https://prometheus-community.github.io/helm-charts)
Looking at the [value.yaml](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/values.yaml) file, I should add it under `prometheusSpec.additionalScrapeConfigs`.

But that does not seem to work. I add the following the configuration file under `spec.source`:

```
 helm:
      values: |
        prometheusSpec:
          additionalScrapeConfigs: 
            - job_name: test-name
              static_configs:
              - targets: ['localhost:8080']
```

the desired target does not appear in Prometheus and when looking at it's configuration on the site, the job_name does not appear.
I have a django-backend running on localhost:8080 that exposes it's metrics under `/metrics`.
I have synced ArgoCD multiple times to make sure the most recent version is deployed.

If anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong, I would highly appreciate it.

I tried adding the values in values.yaml and settings them directly. I expected Prometheus to take these values and add them under scrape_configs, but that did not happen. Either my syntax is wrong somewhere or I am adding it at the wrong location.

Comment: change targets to - targets: ['<service name>.<namespace>:8080'] . Ex if your service name is mydjangoapp and its deploymed on lets say dev namespace the line should be  - targets: ['mydjangoapp.dev:8080']